# How to use play-bootstrap in Twirl templates

Tags: scala, playframework, bootstrap-4, play-bootstrap

I'm a play noob and I'm having an hard time trying to figure out which import(s) I need and where to put them in order to use [play-bootstrap](https://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/).
I've added the library as a dependency (`"com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap" % "1.5.1-P27-B4"`), then in my template, I'm trying to use:

```
@b4.vertical.form(routes.AccountController.handleSubscriptionForm) { implicit vfc =>
    @helper.CSRF.formField

    @b4.email(form("email"))
    // ...and so on
}
```

But the template fail to compile with a weird error message:

```
Expected '"' but found 'EOF'
```

I'm sure I need somehow to import `@b4` into the template context but I don't understand how.

PS. I'm able to use the "standard" play helpers without any issue, the following works perfectly:

```
@helper.form(routes.AccountController.handleSubscriptionForm) {
    @helper.CSRF.formField

    @helper.inputText(form("email"))
```

What I have to do in order to use the play bootstrap helpers?

Comment: Any update on this question?